Positron IDE can't find the Python path
I just installed Positron IDE based on Visual Studio Code, I can work with R programming language and Python, but it doesn't run python code, R is set up as global, Python is set up as global but every time I run a python script it shows up the path doesn't exist and shows me a python path of old python versions, could you help me with that?
Everything seems to be in place, the R kernel thats works just fine and the python kernel is all setup with a huge green light on it, but I can't run any code.
As I'm writing this post this message just showed up about R:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello, if you see the path to the older Python version, your Python interpreter may not be recognized. You can check if the python.pythonPath in the settings.json file is the correct path. Then reselect the interpreter by the Select Interpreter. Then see if can achieve the desired result.
